# this statement is an atomic operation?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j - just started playing with it yesterday.
I have a question - is this statement an atomic operation?

```
start n = node(68362), n1 = node(68363) match n-[r]->n1 delete r;
```

Answer (score 0):

YES. If you haven't started the transaction explicitly then Neo4j Server will start one and execute this statement and complete the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you mean whether neo4j locks any data when executing this delete statement.
than the answer is NO.